# Will you please tell me how to get boolean true or false while using element.isPresent() and element.isDispalyed() in if clause in Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

Will you please tell me how to get boolean true or false while using `element.isPresent()` and `element.isDispalyed()` in if clause in Protractor.

Comment: It isn't already? Your post has a typo of `isDispalyed` instead of `isDisplayed`; maybe that's it?

Comment: Please priovide code sample. It will  be easier to answer

Comment: they return a Promise. You need to either `await` on it or use the `.then` function

Comment: Sample program be       if(webelement.isDisplayed())  {return "False"}                                  webelement.isDisplayed is not working in if clause

Comment: TL;DR: this won’t ever work, use `.then`.